# CTE does not match subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to rewrite the following query.

```
Select distinct A.Account
  from SourceTable A 
 where A.ActivityDate = ( select MAX(ActivityDate) 
                           from SourceTable B 
                          where b.Account = A.Account )
   and A.Status = 'M'
```

I switched to a CTE:

```
;With TableCTE as 
( Select Account,
         row_number() Over (partition by Account order by ActivityDate desc) as Rn 
    From SourceTable
   Where Status = 'M')

Select Account From TableCTE Where Rn  = 1
```

I would expect these queries to have the same results, however, the first one get about 170k rows, and the second get about 380k (and no, its not producing dups).

any thoughts I why I'm getting different amounts?

Comment: Is ActivityDate nullable?

Comment: no, Activity date is a required field

Comment: Easiest way to figure it out is look at one of the accounts that is in the cte that isn't in the first query.

Answer (score 3):

You're applying the `A.Status = 'M'` condition in different places:

In query 1, you're asking for the row with BOTH the highest `ActivityDate` AND `Status = 'M'`

In query 2, you're asking for the row with the highest `ActivityDate` *of the rows where* `Status = 'M'`

The straight SQL equivalent of yout CTE query would be:

```
Select distinct A.Account
from SourceTable A 
where A.ActivityDate = ( select MAX(ActivityDate) 
                           from SourceTable B 
                          where b.Account = A.Account 
                          and b.Status = 'M'
                       )
    and a.Status = 'M'
```

(assuming `ActivityDate` is unique per `Account`)

Comment: In the 2nd query, he's not actually asking for the row with the highest `ActivityDate`.  He's simply partitioning all rows, and getting the row number within the partition.

Comment: The `Where Rn  = 1` in the select will select the highest `ActivityDate` in each partition